# How to make Custom autocomplete in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

how can we create custom *snippet* for **PHP-Language** in atom?

example:

> if i write class then it shows my custom snippet.

Comment: Visual solution on YOUTUBE https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIVY69aBIJQ

Answer (score 9):

Make a snippet in your snippets file!

First, open your snippets file. I use `cmd-shift-p` to search all actions and then type `snippets` and then select `Application: Open Your Snippets` to open the snippets file. Then you can use the `snip` snippet to create a new snippet! For example:

```
'.text.html.php':
  'Class':
    'prefix': 'class'
    'body': 'Your template'
```

Atom uses the `cson` format for the snippets and other editor files. (CSON is CoffeeScript JSON)

Comment: @DilipSuthar If my solution worked, could you mark it as correct?

Comment: actually answer is not more specific in detailed i learned from youtube link given in questions comment.

Comment: the scope for php is '.text.html.php' not '.source.php'